# Pipenv error "bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Tags: python, path, pipenv, pyenv

I am trying to install requirements from a pipfile however when I type `pipenv` and press enter, i receive this error message `-bash: /Users/jkelly/.local/bin/pipenv: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/bin/python3.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` This python directory doesn't exist. I am unable to execute pipenv.

`python --version` returns `Python 3.6.6`. I manage all my versions of python with pyenv.

This is a complete list of all of my pyenv shims

```
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/2to3
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/2to3-3.6
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/easy_install
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/easy_install-3.6
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/idle
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/idle3
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/idle3.6
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/pip
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/pip3
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/pip3.6
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/pydoc
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/pydoc3
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/pydoc3.6
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/python
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/python-config
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/python3
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/python3-config
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/python3.6
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/python3.6-config
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/python3.6m
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/python3.6m-config
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/pyvenv
/Users/jkelly/.pyenv/shims/pyvenv-3.6
```

pipenv is installed via pipsi. This error seems to have nothing to do with the Pipfile. I must have an improperly configured path somewhere.

```
export PATH=/Users/jkelly/.local/bin:$PATH
export PYENV_SHELL=bash
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mongodb@3.6/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@6/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:$PATH"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Comment: I have uninstalled pipenv from pipsi and installed pipenv via homebrew instead and problem seems to have disappeared. If anyone can let me know what the issue likely was that would be great!

Answer (score 5):

On Mac OSX, I solved this by doing

`brew install --force pipenv`

then

`brew link --overwrite pipenv`

to do a reinstall.

Comment: Could you elaborate what these commands do and how they fix the issue?

Comment: It will force the install of pipenv and re-link to it. If the install or the link is broken which was my case, this should resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had two versions of pipenv on my mac. I uninstalled both and re-installed with brew. Voila!

```
pip3 uninstall pipenv
brew uninstall pipenv
brew install pipenv
```

Now everything works fine.